# Is it possible create more threads that specified in ThreadGroup in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, performance

Is it possible create more threads that specified in ThreadGroup in Jmeter? I need to make a test with 10 threads and 10 iterations with a random pause of 2 to 5 seconds between requests. As I know timers are for requests, Ramp up is for threads, but I can't make it work correctly with ${__Random(2,5)}. How can I solve this case?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure about if this will help, since your looking for adding more thread but based in your question, that you can't make it work with `${__Random(2,5)}`. I will suggest try adding `Uniform Random Timer` instead.
This will have two 2 parameter.

- Random Delay Maximum: Where it will decide the max random pause time
- Constant Delay Offset: This is fixed delay time which will be added in random delay.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to make a test with 10 threads and 10 iterations with a random pause of 2 to 5 seconds between requests

Just add a [Constant Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Timer) at the same level as your request [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) live and put the __Random() function there. Just multiply the values by 1000 because Constant Timer uses milliseconds.

[image]

More information: [A Comprehensive Guide to Using JMeter Timers](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/comprehensive-guide-using-jmeter-timers)